# Problem with Regex/Pattern/Matcher

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm trying to implement the ideas in [this post](https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-inbound-email-services-and-regex-to-monitor-apex-error-emails) in my org. However, the provided regex seems to never match anything in any email I throw at it.

The simplest possible test case I can muster is:

```
string plainTextBody = 'Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: ' + userinfo.getUserId().left(15) + '/' + userinfo.getorganizationId().left(15) + '\n';

string regex = '005[A-Za-z0-9]{12}+/(00D[A-Za-z0-9]{12}+)';

Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(plainTextBody);

for(integer i = 1; i <= emailMatcher.groupCount(); i++){
    try {
        system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ emailMatcher.group(' + i + ') ' + emailMatcher.group(i));
    } catch (exception e){
        system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ NOTHING IN THE GROUP');
    }
}
```

The result of this is

```
14:15:26.19 (21080541)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|WARN|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ NOTHING IN THE GROUP
```

Can anyone explain why my regex (or the one in the linked post) doesn't work "as advertised".

Answer (score 1):

Seems I've found my own answer (after mucking around with this for nearly an hour before posting).

If I update the code to the following, all appears to work as I expect:

```
string plainTextBody = 'Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: ' + userinfo.getUserId().left(15) + '/' + userinfo.getorganizationId().left(15) + '\n';

string regex = '(005[A-Za-z0-9]{12}+)/(00D[A-Za-z0-9]{12}+)';

Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(plainTextBody);

if (emailMatcher.find()){
    for(integer i = 1; i <= emailMatcher.groupCount(); i++){
        try {
            system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ emailMatcher.group(' + i + ') ' + emailMatcher.group(i));
        } catch (exception e){
            system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ NOTHING IN THE GROUP');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to go over the differences between this and your original code so that others might learn from this? I can see the difference now, but it's easy to gloss over.

Comment: Fair point. The change is that I've wrapped the for loop in 'if (emailMatcher.find()){}'. This appears to actually apply the regex to the input string, returning the different groups.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach likely does not do what you think it does. If you want to find all partial matches in your input string, you should use this looping structure instead:

```
while (emailMatcher.find())               // there is another partial match
{
    String result = emailMatcher.group(); // get the entire matched string
                                          // .group() is equivalent to .group(0)
                                          // it's going to look like '005.../00D...'
    String orgId = emailMatcher.group(1);
}
```

If you want to get multiple matched parts within a string, that's where you might start to use `.group(i)`, but if you are building an expression where you do not already know the `groupCount`, your code is too complex (you do know `groupCount = 1` in your own code example). Also, never catch a generic `Exception`. You should not be using a `catch` block unless you know what type might be thrown.

Now, here's how it might look instead if you wanted to match both the User Id and the Organization Id:

```
String expression = '(005\\w{12})/(00D\\w{12})';
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(expression).match(plainTextBody);
while (m.find())
{
    String userId = m.group(1); // you know this grouping corresponds to 005\w{12}
    String orgId = m.group(2);  // you know this grouping corresponds to 00D\w{12}
}
```

Comment: Per the original post I linked to, the actual regex is very complex and does do what I am after.

Comment: The point is you are using the wrong looping structure. You should use `while (emailMatcher.find())` in case there are multiple matches, then match each group by its index (starting at `1`).